# Is it possible to use filter and filterPredicate both in angular material?

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material

I can only use either the function of filter or filterPredicate.

When I try to use it both function (filter + filterPredicate ) in one component.

filter function will generate a error:

```
"core.js:14597 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0"
```

It will works fine only if I use filter or filterPredicate.

Below is the Component and the Component.ts:

HTML:

```
      <mat-form-field class="search-form-field" floatLabel="never">
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyFilter()">
      </mat-form-field>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="dataYear">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                  <mat-form-field class="searchIncolumn">
                    <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Year" [formControl]="yearFilter" />
                </mat-form-field>
              </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dataYear}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

TS:

```
yearFilter = new FormControl();
displayedColumns: string[] = ['dataYear'];

NgOnit() {
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
    response => {
      this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(<any> response);
      this.listData.sort = this.sort;
      this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.listData.filterPredicate = this.tableFilter();
    }
    ,errorResponse => { console.log(errorResponse); }
      );
}

tableFilter(): (data: any, filter: string) => boolean {
  let filterFunction = function(data, filter): boolean {
    let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
    return data.dataYear.toString().indexOf(searchTerms.dataYear) !== -1
          && data.dataMonth.indexOf(searchTerms.dataMonth) !== -1
          && data.sources.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.sources) !== -1
          && data.population.toString().indexOf(searchTerms.population) !== -1; 
  }
  return filterFunction;

} 


applyFilter() {
  this.listData.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: That suggests that your "JSON" is not all structured and has a non-escaped special characters during JSON parse. Look at the data you are getting back from the server.

Comment: @AliBenMessaoud
Thanks for your comment first...
The data structure for filter is String and filterPredicate  is ((data: T, filter: string) => boolean)
So how can I apply it together?

Answer (score 0):

FILTERPREDICATE OVERRIDES FILTER

### filter: string

Filter term that should be used to filter out objects from the data array. To override how data objects match to this filter string, provide a custom function for filterPredicate.

### filterPredicate: (data: T, filter: string) => boolean

Checks if a data object matches the data source's filter string. By default, each data object is converted to a string of its properties and returns true if the filter has at least one occurrence in that string. By default, the filter string has its whitespace trimmed and the match is case-insensitive. May be overridden for a custom implementation of filter matching.